# How to find 1st occurrence in line of: ,"", and replace with: ," ", using Notepad++ with regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I want to replace **the 1st occurrence** on each line using Notepad++ find/replace with Regex.

Find:         `,"",`

Replace with: `,"  ",`

In other words, insert 2 spaces between the 2 double quotes.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as following regex.

- Find what: `,"",(.*)$`
- Replace with: `,"  ",\1`
- Search Mode: Regular expression

Input:

```
this is a ,"", here and another is here ,"", at the end
next ,"",,"", here ,"",
another one ,"",
,"", last one
```

Expected result:

```
this is a ,"  ", here and another is here ,"", at the end
next ,"  ",,"", here ,"",
another one ,"  ",
,"  ", last one
```

Comment: Thanks for this AFSHIN. I found a different solution Find what: (^.*?)\K,"", Replace with: ,"  ", but this only works if you click Replace All. Yours is defiantly a better solution